# Is there a difference between two classes both inherited from NSObject but one marked with @objc in Swift?

Tags: swift

I wonder whether `@objc` would add some extra functionality for those classes inherited from NSObject in Swift.

This is Swift 5.0 with Xcode 10.2.1.

```
@objc class X: NSObject {
    var x = 0
}

class Y: NSObject {
    var y = 0
}
```

Is there a semantic difference between these two classes in Swift's perspective?

Comment: Yes, X can be used from Objective C

Comment: @Paulw11 is `@objc` enough? Shouldn't `X` also be `public`?

Comment: No, `public` isn't relevant to ObjC visibility.

Comment: @Losiowaty `public` is required if X is in a framework and you want to access it from another, objective-C target. If X is part of the same target then public is not required

Comment: There's no semantic difference between the two – inheriting from an `@objc` class (such as `NSObject`) automatically makes the class `@objc` unless it's generic. But IMO explicitly marking it `@objc` is good for clarity as it clearly signals that you expect it to be used in Obj-C code.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference here is that `class X` can be called from Objective-C and `class Y` cannot. The fact that they both inherit from `NSObject` is a completely separate thing.

It's the exact same as having to classes that inherit from `UIViewController`, if one has the `@objc` prefix it can be called from Objective-C code and the other can't, doesn't have anything to do with the fact that they are `UIViewController` subclasses.

Comment: `class Y` can be accessed from Objective-C, it's inferred to be `@objc` by the compiler because it inherits from an `@objc` class and isn't generic.